# How do I make a colored border to the highest number of population in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, max, border

Hello Im doing a project for school in Javascript and restCountries API https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v3-all. you can search on language and the countries that speaks its language shows in result. It also comes a errormessage if the language doesnt excist. To the country that speaks the language and has the highest population needs a border around it to stand out. How do I make a colored border around the div with the country that has the highest population? Thanks in Advance!

Script code;

```
const countries = document.querySelector('.countries')
const lang = document.getElementById('search').value
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')


async function getCountries(){
    countries.innerText = ''
    const search = document.querySelector('.search').value;
    const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/lang/${search}`,{
        method: "GET",
    });
    
    const data = await response.json();

    if(!response.ok){
        countries.innerText += 'Language doesnt excist. Search again!'
      
    }else {
        data.forEach(api=> {
            showCountry(api)
        })  
    }

    ??const maxPopulation = Math.max(data?.population)
    maxPopulation.forEach(pop =>{
        pop.style.border = 'green'
    })
    }
 

function showCountry(data){
    const country = document.createElement('div')
    country.classList.add('country')
    countries.classList.add('countriesClass')
    country.innerHTML =
    `<div class="country-img">
        <img src="${data?.flags?.png}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="country-details">
        <h5 class="countryName">${data?.name?.common}</h5>
        <p><strong>Population:</strong>${data?.population}</p>
        <p><strong>SubRegion:</strong>${data?.subregion}</p>
        <p><strong>Capital:</strong>${data?.capital}</p>
    </div>`
    
    countries.appendChild(country)
     
}
```

html code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Search country by language!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="controls">
            <i class="bx bx-search"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search by language.." id="search" class="search">
        </div>
        <button id="btn" onclick="getCountries()">Search Country</button>
    </div>
    <div class="countries">
              
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, however your `maxPopulation` is not working as you think it would.

In order to get the `maxPopulation` of **all** the countries you need to *map* all the data.

You could do this by `const allPopulations = data.map(country => country.population)`

In order to get the max value from `allPopulations` you can put this in the `Math.max` method you used as well.

`const maxPopulation = Math.max(...allPupulations)`

*Notice how we *spread* the `allPopulations` in the `Math.max` method, this is because `allPopulations` is an array or numbers while the `Math.max` expects just a list of numbers like `Math.max(1,2,3,4)`*

A working example can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hawking-hlmfn2?file=/src/index.js

Good luck with the rest of your project!